# IEnumerable.OfType() not working as expected

Tags: linq, ienumerable

I have a dictionary of objects, all of different types but derived from the same base class, and wanted to find a specific one. I thought I could filter the dictionary for objects of a given type using ".OfType()", but didn't find anything.

What did I not understand ?

```
class Program
{
  static Dictionary<String, Animal> critters;

  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
     critters = new Dictionary<String, Animal>();
     critters.Add("Tiddles", new Cat());
     critters.Add("Rover", new Dog());
     critters.Add("Bob", new Fish());

     Animal rover = GetAnimal<Dog>();
  }

  // Finds first animal of the specified type.
  static T GetAnimal<T>() where T : Animal
  {
     var qry = from animal in critters.OfType<T>()
               select animal;
     return (qry.Count() > 0) ? qry.First() : null;
  }
}

class Animal { }
class Dog : Animal { }
class Cat : Animal { }
class Fish : Animal { }
```

Thanks,

Ross

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because dictionary IEnumarable is returning a [`<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k3z2hhax.aspx).  Use the [Values](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ekcfxy3x.aspx) from it.

---

I would also suggest that you change the last line in  your GetAnimal from

```
return (qry.Count() > 0) ? qry.First() : null;
```

There is no need to waste a .Count() operation on qry, just use FirstOrDefault, it does the same thing.

```
return qry.FirstOrDefault();
```

You can reduce it, and not lose any readability, to:

```
return critters.Values.OfType<T>().FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: There's also no point in having an empty query expression like that. Just `critters.OfType<T>().FirstOrDefault()` would be best...

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's because of the "critters" dictionary. You should add "Values" property to your query. Try next:

```
static T GetAnimal<T>() where T : Animal
  {
     var qry = from animal in critters.Values.OfType<T>()
               select animal;
     return (qry.Count() > 0) ? qry.First() : null;
  }
```